# Result type of date math in HQL

Tags: sql, date, hql

Here's a very simple question which I surprisingly have not been able to find a clear answer for by Googling:

If I try to find the difference between two dates in HQL, will I get an integer in return? To be more specific, my dates are of type 'YYYY-MM-DD.' Here's an example of what I'd like to see:

'2014-11-03'   -   '2014-10-30' = 4

Also, as a follow up question, how could I find out this out for myself by querying? :)

Thanks!
Clark

Answer (score 0):

If you use `MySQL` you can use [DATEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function.
You should register this SQL function or use native query.